# Best way to count char occurences in a string

Tags: python, string, optimization, performancecounter

Hello I am trying to write these python lines in a single line but getting some errors due to the dictionary modifications the code is doing.

```
for i in range(len(string)):
    if string[i] in dict:
        dict[string[i]] += 1
```

the general syntax I believe is

```
abc = [i for i in len(x) if x[i] in array]
```

Would it be possible for someone to tell me how this might work considering that I am adding 1 to the value in a dictionary

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear, what `dict` have before loop? If it's empty, then no character will be counted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're trying to do can be done with **`dict`**, a **generator expression** and [**`str.count()`**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.count):

```
abc = dict((c, string.count(c)) for c in string)
```

**Alternative** using `set(string)` *(from a comment down below by `soulcheck`)*:

```
abc = dict((c, string.count(c)) for c in set(string))
```

---

#### Timing

Seen the comments down below I performed a little testing among this and other answers. *(with python-3.2)*

***Test functions:***

```
@time_me
def test_dict(string, iterations):
    """dict((c, string.count(c)) for c in string)"""
    for i in range(iterations):
        dict((c, string.count(c)) for c in string)

@time_me
def test_set(string, iterations):
    """dict((c, string.count(c)) for c in set(string))"""
    for i in range(iterations):
        dict((c, string.count(c)) for c in set(string))

@time_me
def test_counter(string, iterations):
    """Counter(string)"""
    for i in range(iterations):
        Counter(string)

@time_me
def test_for(string, iterations, d):
    """for loop from cha0site"""
    for i in range(iterations):
        for c in string:
            if c in d:
                d[c] += 1

@time_me
def test_default_dict(string, iterations):
    """defaultdict from joaquin"""
    for i in range(iterations):
        mydict = defaultdict(int)
        for mychar in string:
            mydict[mychar] += 1
```

***Test execution:***

```
d_ini = dict((c, 0) for c in string.ascii_letters)
words = ['hand', 'marvelous', 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious']

for word in words:
    print('-- {} --'.format(word))
    test_dict(word, 100000)
    test_set(word, 100000)
    test_counter(word, 100000)
    test_for(word, 100000, d_ini)
    test_default_dict(word, 100000)
    print()

print('-- {} --'.format('Pride and Prejudcie - Chapter 3 '))

test_dict(ch, 1000)
test_set(ch, 1000)
test_counter(ch, 1000)
test_for(ch, 1000, d_ini)
test_default_dict(ch, 1000)
```

***Test results:***

```
-- hand --
389.091 ms -  dict((c, string.count(c)) for c in string)
438.000 ms -  dict((c, string.count(c)) for c in set(string))
867.069 ms -  Counter(string)
100.204 ms -  for loop from cha0site
241.070 ms -  defaultdict from joaquin

-- marvelous --
654.826 ms -  dict((c, string.count(c)) for c in string)
729.153 ms -  dict((c, string.count(c)) for c in set(string))
1253.767 ms -  Counter(string)
201.406 ms -  for loop from cha0site
460.014 ms -  defaultdict from joaquin

-- supercalifragilisticexpialidocious --
1900.594 ms -  dict((c, string.count(c)) for c in string)
1104.942 ms -  dict((c, string.count(c)) for c in set(string))
2513.745 ms -  Counter(string)
703.506 ms -  for loop from cha0site
935.503 ms -  defaultdict from joaquin

# !!!: Do not compare this last result with the others because is timed
#      with 1000 iterations instead of 100000
-- Pride and Prejudcie - Chapter 3  --
155315.108 ms -  dict((c, string.count(c)) for c in string)
982.582 ms -  dict((c, string.count(c)) for c in set(string))
4371.579 ms -  Counter(string)
1609.623 ms -  for loop from cha0site
1300.643 ms -  defaultdict from joaquin
```

Comment: to be precise the first solution is a generator expression passed to `dict()` constructor, the second one is dict comprehension

Comment: Isn't this slightly bad, complexity wise? I think it's `O(n*n)`, while the original was `O(n)` (Well, `O(n*n)` worst case because of the hash table lookup, but `O(n)` on average)...

Comment: Just a note: alternative syntax requires Python 2.7 or newer.

Comment: @cha0site true, but you can easlily modify it to have the same running time: `abc = dict((c, string.count(c)) for c in set(string))`

Comment: @soulcheck: Mmmm... That's not quite the problem, the problem is with the `count` method being `O(n)`. Your version still has polynomial running time (consider the case of `"hand"` or other words which already have unique letters).

Comment: @cha0site ah, didn't notice that. true

Comment: @cha0site: I timed all the solutions, the problem with your loop is in `if c in dict` with all the ascii letters in `dict`.

Comment: @soulcheck: I timed your solution with `set(string)` and it's very good. Maybe you want to take a look at it :)

Comment: @JohnMachin: I timed even his solution and I agree it the best *(maybe you want to check it above)*. I think there's need to down-vote me since I show that, and I took the effort of timeing all the answers.

Comment: @RikPoggi it essencially makes an O(n^2) algorithm an O(n*d) one, where n= length of string, d = size of the alphabet. Here d is constant so you're ok. You still should prefer reclosedev's or joaquin's solution, depending on the python version you're using, as it's O(n) and definitely more general.

Comment: @Rik: The dict lookup is expensive? I find this surprising, it should be one of the cheaper operations there. Thanks for the work =)

Comment: The only semi-meaningful test is with the book chapter; you should do a few iterations and take the best timing.

Comment: @cha0site: That seemed strange to me too, so I checkd the functions and I found returns where they souldn't be. I'm sorry for the mistake! I edited my results *(double checked)*.

Comment: @JohnMachin: Thanks for the advice, I did that. I also found a mistake in my previous timing so they weren't reliable, they should be now. *Sorry*

Comment: @RikPoggi, +1 for timings. Interesting results. I knew that `Counter` is slow, but `string.count() ... set(string)` is surprising.

Comment: @Rik: Very interesting results... We can see that the first solution is slow for large values of n, as you'd expect, and the rest are about the same (multiplied by some constant). I find it surprising that the second solution (the one with the `set`) actually ran _faster_ for a larger value of n...

Comment: @cha0site: Thanks! I just wanted to time them on a real text but the resuts can't be compared with the others: the loop on the chapter-text has 100 less iterations, but since is 100 times longer the results are similar. I wrote `[less iterations]` before, but now I made that more clear.

Comment: @Rik: Yeah, it might be the iterations. Anyway, we're coding in Python here - for all intents and purposes, the runtime of the bottom 4 solutions is the same.

Comment: Hey guys, please take extended discussions to one of the [chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) instead of using comments.  Thanks.

Comment: Hello just wanted to know if I can somehow incorporate 
`d = {s: string.count(s) for s in string if s in d}; d['C'] /= 2` into one line. My code works fine but I am interested in making it as short as possible for the heck of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This is a job for the collections module:

---

**Option 1.-** [**collections. defaultdict**](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> mydict = defaultdict(int)
```

then your loop becomes:

```
>>> for mychar in mystring: mydict[mychar] += 1
```

---

**Option 2.-**  [**collections.Counter**](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)  (From Felix comment):

An alternative that is better for this specific case, and from the same `collections` module:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
```

then you only need (!!!):

```
>>> mydict = Counter(mystring)
```

Counter is only available from python 2.7. So for python < 2.7 you should stay with defaultdict

Comment: I timed your solution against the others and it's the best one, maybe you want to take a look at it. (+1)

Answer (score 7):

Alternative for Python 2.7+:

```
from collections import Counter

abc = Counter('asdfdffa')
print abc
print abc['a']
```

Output:

```
Counter({'f': 3, 'a': 2, 'd': 2, 's': 1})
2
```

Comment: whats the time complexity?

Answer (score 1):

That's not a good candidate for a list comprehension. You usually want to use list comprehensions to make list, and to have side-effects (changing global states) in them is not such a good idea.

One the other hand, your code might be better off like this:

```
for c in string:
    if c in dict:
        dict[c] += 1
```

Or if you really want to get functional (I've renamed `dict` to `d` because I need python's built-in `dict` function):

```
d.update(dict([ (c, d[c]+1, ) for c in string ]))
```

Notice how I did **not** change `d` within the list comprehension, but instead updated `d` outside of it.

Comment: -1 Looks horrible and doesn't work. `d = {}; d.update(dict([ (c, d[c]+1, ) for c in 'fubar' ]))` produces `KeyError: 'f'`
. Changing the `d[c]` to `d.get(c, 0)` avoids the KeyError but it STILL doesn't because d is not updated in the loop do `d[c]` can never be greater than 0, so *all the counts are 1*.

Comment: @John: Depends on what you want to do. The original question assumes that there's something in the `dict`, so I did as well.

Comment: And the first suggestion requires the dict to be initialised to 0 for all expected characters -- that's not robust.

Answer (score -1):

Your original loop is hopelessly unPythonic. There's no need to iterate through `range(len(string))` if all you want is to iterate through the letters in `string`. Do this instead:

```
for c in my_string:
    if c in my_dict:
        my_dict[c] += 1
```

Comment: -1 You forgot either the `else: my_dict[c] = 1` at the end, or the `defaultdict` setup at the start. All the counts will be zero.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> def count(s):
    global k
    list =[]
    for i in s:
        k=0
        if i not in list:
            list.append(i)      
            for j in range(len(s)):
                if i == s[j]:
                    k +=1

            print 'count of char {0}:{1}'.format(i,k)


>>> count('masterofalgorithm')
count of char m:2
count of char a:2
count of char s:1
count of char t:2
count of char e:1
count of char r:2
count of char o:2
count of char f:1
count of char l:1
count of char g:1
count of char i:1
count of char h:1
>>>
```